# How can I import geth accounts into eth?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, private-key, cpp-ethereum

I had two accounts under `~/.ethereum/keystore` when I used `geth` a while ago.

I got a new PC, recompiled only the C++ version and I can't *see* my two accounts in `eth`.

`web3.admin.eth.allAccounts()` returns only an account that seems stored under ~/.web3/keys if I'm not mistaken.

Is it possible that I somewhat import my `geth` accounts in `eth`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ethkey](https://gavofyork.gitbooks.io/turboethereum/content/ethkey.html) tool that is included with eth.

Simply import the wallet with

`ethkey import mygethkey.json "My Key Name"`

Just replace `mygethkey.json` with the path to the key file.