# cpp-ethereum (Homestead) starts resyncing blockchain

Tags: synchronization, cpp-ethereum, homestead, linux, ubuntu

I just installed cpp-ethereum 1.2.2 in order to upgrade to Homestead. When eth is started it begins to re-sync the blockchain from block 1, while the whole blockchain is already on my machine. 
Is this necessary? 
Is there a way to reuse the blockchain already present in .ethereum/chaindata?

Comment: which version did you have before the upgrade?

Comment: I had geth installed previously. In the meantime the whole blockchain is synced again.

Answer (score 1):

The Go Ethereum (`geth`) and Turbo Ethereum (`eth`) do not share the same blockchain and data directory. If you switch your client from `geth` to `eth` you will have to redownload the whole blockchain again. Also you have to migrate your accounts.

To upgrade `geth` to homestead, install version 1.3.5, or import your accounts to `eth`: [How can I import geth accounts into eth?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1472/87)

If you decided to switch to the new client, you will have to download the blockchain again.