# what is a private key in an ethereum wallet like metamask? and how do I find it?

Tags: metamask, private-key

my question is about what a private key is? and where would I find it on an ewallet like metamask?

Comment: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vge3G.jpg)
I've lost my money and I don't know how would find my deposit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can export your private key in metamask doing the following

> if you only want to export a single account to another wallet, you can click the "Export Private Key" option on the Account Detail view. Currently, that's the key icon:

[image]

Source : [Exporting a MetaMask Account](http://metamask.consensyssupport.happyfox.com/kb/article/18-exporting-a-metamask-account)

Already answered question about the private key: [What is the Private Key?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19257/what-is-the-private-key/19296)

Comment: thank you, and one last question, when and for what reason would you use your private key or export your private key for?

Comment: @Etherneum It's for when you want to manage one of your MetaMask accounts from another Ethereum client. It's good practice to back up your private keys and the 12 words metamask gave you when you created your account so that if something happens you can recover your wallet. Also never share those two information with anyone.

Comment: the password I use for metamask is different from the private key right? and if I export my private key does that mean I will have access to view my private key? what is the recommended way to back up my private key and 12 word pass phrase?

Comment: @Etherneum Yes your password and private key is completely different. If someone has the private key of your account they could easily import your account in their wallet and steal your ETH. When you export your private key you'll have to enter your password and it will show you your private key. Then you could import it in a other wallet on a different pc for example. It's your choice on how you want to back up your information, you could write it down on a piece of paper, save it as a file or even place it in a safe in a bank.

Comment: hear you loud and clear, I have always been a technophobe and not the most tech savy. thank you for explaining things to me

Comment: is there a crypto exchange you recommend?

Comment: @Etherneum If you're in the US Coinbase is pretty simple to get started. My advice is to not keep your crypto assets in those exchange sites, simply use them to buy and sell the crypto currency you want. You can look into Exodus which is a desktop wallet that allows you to hold multiple different crypto currencies. There's also Shapeshift that allows you to exchange between crypto currencies.

Comment: yeah i heard lots of people had negative reviews on exodus because of the high rate fees for BTC and Shapeshift is the parent company of Exodus I believe. I dont really know the difference between them thought but I hear shapeshift is cheaper

Comment: What format is this, base16 (hex)?

Answer (score 0):

For those like me using the newest version of metamask. Now we do like this to get secret KEY :

[image]

Then

[image]