# How to extract private keys from Ethereum Wallet?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, private-key, configuration

How to extract private key of an account from Ethereum Wallet on Linux? Please specify the exact filesystem locations.

I need private keys both for the main network and for the Ropsten test network.

Comment: This question and answer posted by me might help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15494/location-of-public-and-private-keys-of-ethereum-account  Note that the paths specified are for the Parity client on a Mac machine. There are links in the answer to other information which you might find helpful, too.

Comment: @AjoyBhatia The answer you refer to is about Parity not about Ethereum Wallet which I ask about

Comment: Oh, OK. I thought "Ethereum Wallet" was meant in a generic sense and the specific client was not specified. Didn't realize that is a specific piece of software.

Answer (score 2):

The keystore is encrypted and default location in Linux is `~/.ethereum/keystore`.

You can use https://www.myetherwallet.com to get the raw private key. If you want to script this, you can for instance use node.js ethereumjs-wallet library.

Also see [How do I get the raw private key from my Mist keystore file?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3720/how-do-i-get-the-raw-private-key-from-my-mist-keystore-file)

Comment: How can https://www.myetherwallet.com extract the private key from a file located at my filesystem (not on the network)?

Comment: You have to upload the key to the javascript app (which is running in your local browser and not on the server) and unlock it.

Comment: I cannot see anywhere to get my raw private key on myetherwallet, can you please elaborate