# how to decrypt aes 128 keystore offline with password

Tags: web3js, wallets, javascript, ethereum-classic, keystore

i want to create dapp like cold wallet on which i can access my sign transaction with private key but in order to get private key for each time i need offline code or script to **decrypt my keystore that is in aes-128** ,with the help of password i want to get private key back to other function.

basically it should work like myetherwallet walletinfo/keystore or metamask kinda

any tutorial or document will work.. thanks

Comment: This answer in particular https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/36022/