# How to decrypt private key form keystore file, without using third party applications?

Tags: private-key

I would like to write a piece of code that takes input as UTC key store file and password, and returns decrypted Private Key. I am aware of options like "MyEtherWallet" but I would like to do using my code. Any help/resources that I can use is appreciated.

Comment: In particular this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/36022/

Comment: I guess this question is more about decrypting without depending on specific applications like geth or JS packages. If so, this actually is asking the underlying details of the linked answers. I have created a new answer which hopefully has more "hands-on" details https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/47135/20451

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Javascript library [**ethereumjs-wallet**](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet) which allows to load a wallet from a private key, seed phrase or UTC JSON file (V1 or V3)

I have generated a UTC JSON file on MyEtherWallet and the sample code below shows how to decrypt it to sign transactions:

```
const Wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet'),
      fs = require('fs');


const utcFile = "./UTC--2018-04-29T10-08-25.072Z--1f7c98090febf46155496a370002a10af7eb6766"
const password = "password123"


const myWallet = Wallet.fromV3(fs.readFileSync(utcFile).toString(), password, true);

console.log("Private Key: " + myWallet.getPrivateKey().toString('hex')) 
console.log("Address: " + myWallet.getAddress().toString('hex'))
```

**Output**

```
$ node index.js 
Private Key: 8ecb2c8c4fcf3986e5d3c249bac183b206f41a7a2d9a81e203ef6219be87421b
Address: 1f7c98090febf46155496a370002a10af7eb6766
```

I pushed some of the code [here](https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/47031-how-to-decrypt-private-key-form-keystore-file-without-using-third-party-applica)