# Getting private keys of geth accounts

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, accounts, private-key, export

Just the opposite of this question [How to import a plain private key into geth or Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist) I would like to know how can I obtain the private keys of the accounts created with geth in this way:

```
$ geth --testnet account new
```

I've been looking for private key files on ~/.ethereum/keystore but there is only one file for coinbase account. No files for the rest of accounts created.

How can I obtain those missing files? Why are they missing? Thx!

I've already seen [How can I import geth accounts into eth?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1472/how-can-i-import-geth-accounts-into-eth) but problem is in my system keystore files don't even exist for most of the geth accounts created, except coinbase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For test net, the folder you are looking for is `~/.ethereum/testnet/keystore/`.

Comment: Thx! Absolutely right.

Comment: in case you will use windows check  %AppData%\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\keystore

Comment: On Mac, it's `~/Library/Ethereum/testnet`

Comment: this answer is incorrect. JSON account file is not the private key. Private key is a 64 byte sequence encoded in HEX.To get this key you have to decrypt the JSON file first.

Comment: @Nulik and how do you do that?

Comment: Would something here be useful? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37182/how-to-get-private-through-utc-files-in-keystore