# Private key needed or not for sending transaction in ethereum

Tags: web3js, web3.py

In web3 APIs I could not see an option to specify private key for sending a transaction in [doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send). How this is done then ? My understanding is that we need private key of a particular account to send transaction.

Comment: Have you tried personal.unlockAccount()? http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.personal.html#web3.personal.unlockAccount You can unlock the account that you specified in from field then the client will use the corresponding private key for signing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

web3 sends transactions using unlocked wallets, which requires that you unlock your account using the keyfile and the password prior to sending a transaction. web3 is then able to access the the private key from the unlocked wallet and sign the transaction.

If you want to avoid unlocking the wallet, you need to sign the transaction yourself and send a raw transaction using eth.sendRawTransaction.

Unfortunately, web3 does not support signing of transactions. However, you can sign a transactrion using [ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx). To obtain a hex string `serializedTx` containing the signed transaction use

```
const tx = new EthereumTx(txParams); 
tx.sign(privateKey);
let serializedTx = "0x" + tx.serialize().toString('hex');
```

`serializedTx` can be used with eth.sendRawTransaction.

For signing the transactions, the private key `privateKey`is needed. If you don't have the private key, you can use [myetherwallet.com](http://myetherwallet.com) to obtain it from a keyfile and the passphrase, or you can optain the private key programatically from a keyfile and the password using

```
let privateKey = keythereum.recover(password, keyObject);
```

from [keyethereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum). `keyObject` is the content of the keyfile, which is a JSON string.

Comment: Thanks @gisdev_p for the reply. I got the concept now. One query is that How can I sign the smart contract transactions ? If I am moving with the ethereumjs-tx way other than web3 pass phrase way.

Comment: Actually, there is no difference if you make a transaction to a normal account or a contract. The handling of the transaction and the signing ist the same. That you will typically have a data part with a transaction to a contract, but most likely not with a transaction to a normal account, does not have any influence on the signing. You just add the data part to the transation and sign it.

Comment: The process is documented [in full here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction)

Answer (score 1):

The signing of the transaction is handled by the [Provider](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/include_package-core.html?highlight=provider#providers) set on the web3 object.

For example, if the user is interacting with a Dapp through a browser then it is likely that the provider is MetaMask and this will handle the user authorising the transactions.

Comment: I am actually trying from server. From my python Django application. How can I do it then with web3.py ?

Comment: I'm curious based-on what you just said, if I'm using built-in provider e.g. web3.providers.HttpProvider does it do transaction signing?

Comment: @c.sokun, if you have a local Ethereum node running and the RPC API exposed then that node will handle the TX signing