# Details about w3.eth.account.create()

Tags: web3js, cpp-ethereum

I am currently getting started into developing involving Ethereum. I know what the function `w3.eth.account.create()` does and returns but I am unsure what happens behind the scenes.

Specifically, does the function store anything on the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a pair of a public and private key. The created object also contains functions to sign transactions and messages using the key pair. This does not store anything on the computer, contrary to [`web3.eth.personal.newAccount`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#newaccount) which will store a keyfile on the computer, with the information of the private key, encrypted and secured with a password.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, with regards to the keyfile, can you access it to retrieve the private key and password?

Comment: The password is set by you so you know it, the private key can be extracted with that password, see [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12830/how-to-get-private-key-from-account-address-and-password)