# create new account using personal.newAccount

Tags: go-ethereum

How to retrieve their private and public key.I created one ethereum address using command line personal.newAccount .When I am checking this address in etherscan it shows 0 balance but in my ethereum geth its shows have balance.Where I can see the my private ethereum blockchain detail with all transaction.I setup mist wallet also but its not working.Please Help.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get private through UTC files in keystore](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37182/how-to-get-private-through-utc-files-in-keystore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer you one by one.

**How to retrieve your public and private key?**

Inside your geth directory, you will be able to see the keystore file. 
You can use this node module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/keythereum) to retrieve the private key using the password you used while creating the account.

**When I am checking this address in etherscan it shows 0 balance but in my ethereum geth its shows have balance**

I assume you have created your own private ethereum network and hence you wont be able to see the balance of the account in etherscan. Etherscan are either connected to the mainnet or testnet works (rinkeby,ropsten and  kovan). I am not sure on which etherscan you have checked.

Same applies for mist as well but you can connect mist or metamask to the geth rpc address and view the balance of your account accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your response.Setup private ethereum network on mainnet. I checked etherscan with mainnet.I Installed ethereum wallet .Its open the ethereum wallet window in linux. But its not synchronise with my account and balance.It shows zero balance.

Comment: You cant setup private ethereum network on mainnet. Both are different. I assume you run your own private ethereum network. Can you post more details on how you are running ethereum ?

Comment: I am executing this command when started geth with network id  1 and network id 1 stands for main net.Still my node is not synchronize with ethereum wallet in ethereum wallet it shows 0 balance.
geth --datadir  ethchain --networkid 1 --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin,txpool,debug" --rpc --maxpeers 0 --nodiscover  --rpccorsdomain "http://18.130.64.98" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"  --ipcpath "ethchain/geth.ipc" --syncmode fast console